# oracle query to run from 6am to 4am

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g

got an issue with an Oracle where clause,

I have reporting services connecting to oracle to run a report, the report is refreshed ever 10 minutes.

issues I have is the shift pattern for the place I work is between 6am and 4pm then 4pm till 2am,

I need to get the report to reset back to 0 at 2am and not midnight

the report is very simple and is counting production numbers between the shifts

query is

SELECT nvl(SUM (QUANTITY),0) as TOTAL
from PP
WHERE  CREATEDATETIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 6/24  and TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 > CREATEDATETIME

tried a number of different where clause but at midnight the count goes back to 0

Answer (score 0):

Check what hour of the day it is and if it is before 2am then look at yesterday and today's values and if it is after 2am then look at today and tomorrow's values:

```sql
SELECT nvl(SUM (QUANTITY),0) as TOTAL
from   PP
WHERE  (   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) < 2
       AND CREATEDATETIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '18' HOUR
       AND CREATEDATETIME <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '2' HOUR
       )
OR     (   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) >= 2
       AND CREATEDATETIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
       AND CREATEDATETIME <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1 2' DAY TO HOUR
       );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT nvl(SUM (QUANTITY),0) as TOTAL
from   PP
WHERE  (   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) < 2
       AND CREATEDATETIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 18/24
       AND CREATEDATETIME <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 2/24
       )
OR     (   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) >= 2
       AND CREATEDATETIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 6/24
       AND CREATEDATETIME <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 + 2/24
       );
```

---

Comment: applied the where clause, had an issue with EXTRACT(HOUR from SYSDATE) needed to change it too     EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP)